# How to Get DateDiff by input id, at the same time SQL query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mariadb, date-arithmetic

[MY DB TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6fXq.png)

My Current Code is..

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, Return_Date , Submit_Date )FROM Issue WHERE Book_ID = ?
```

But it shows a error that saying "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'"

Full code is

```
    Connection conn;
    Connct readerconn = new Connct();
    conn =readerconn.getConnection();
    
    
       try{
        String query = "SELECT DATEDIFF(Return_Date , Submit_Date) FROM issue WHERE Book_ID = ?" ;
        Double diff=null;

        PreparedStatement pstnt=conn.prepareStatement(query);           
        pstnt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt( jTextField4.getText()));
        
        try (ResultSet rs = pstnt.executeQuery( query ) ;) {
        while ( rs.next ( ) ) {
            diff = rs.getDouble( 1 ) ;
            
            if(diff<=7){
                Double fine=diff-7*10;
                fine = Double.valueOf(jTextField1.getText());
                
            }
            else{
                showMessageDialog(null,"No Fine");                   
            }
        }
                    
        
        } catch ( SQLException ex ) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReturnNFines.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            showMessageDialog(null,"Error"); 
        }

        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReturnNFines.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        showMessageDialog(null, "Failed");
    }
```

im trying to get he id from JText filed and Find the DateDiff of the row , which has the input id,

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you are using MySQL/MariaDB. In this database, [function `datediff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) takes two arguments only, that are both dates (or the-like).

So:

```
select datediff(return_date , submit_date) from issue where book_id = ?
```

Note that the function actually counts how many day boundaries exist between the two arguments, which, if your arguments have a time component may - or many not - be what you expect; typically, `DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30')` is `1`.

If you want a computation that considers a gap of 24 hours as one day, you can use `timestampdiff()` and arithmetics, as follows:

```
timestampdiff(second, submit_date, return_date) / 60 / 60 / 24
```

This gives you the date difference as a decimal number of days.

Comment: yeah i also tried that but, when tried that way ,error occurs saying                                "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1"

Comment: @MayuraAbesingha: well my answer solves your question,and now you have a different error. The question mark is a parameter, that your application should replace with the proper value. You can run the query with a literal value instead of the `?` to ensure that the solution works, and then search the documentation of the database client you are running for how to manage query parameters.

Comment: im trying to get id from JTEXTFIELD , and find the DateDiff of the certain row which has the input ID,